# numpy.where for row index which that row is not all zero

Tags: python, numpy

I have a large matrix which some rows are all zero. I want to get the index of the row that is not all zero. I tried

```
 idx = np.where(mymatrix[~np.all(mymatrix != 0, axis=1)])
```

and got

```
 (array([  21,   21,   21, ..., 1853, 3191, 3191], dtype=int64),
  array([3847, 3851, 3852, ..., 4148, 6920, 6921], dtype=int64))
```

Is the first array the row index? Is there more straightforward way to get only row index?

Comment: So, do you want : `array([  21,   21,   21, ..., 1853, 3191, 3191]` or `array([  21,, ..., 1853, 3191]`?

Comment: how about  idx[0]?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a straight way:

```
np.where(np.any(arr != 0, axis=1))
```

Answer (score 1):

You are actually close enough to the solution yourself. You need to think a bit what you do inside the `np.where()`.

I get this matrix as an example:

> array([[1, 1, 1, 1],
>          [2, 2, 2, 2],
>          [0, 0, 0, 0],
>          [3, 3, 3, 3]])

```
# This will give you back a boolean array of whether your
# statement is true or false per raw
np.all(mymatrix != 0, axis=1)
```

> array([ True,  True, False,  True], dtype=bool)

Now if you give that to the `np.where()` it will return your desired output:

```
np.where(np.all(mymatrix != 0, axis=1))
```

> (array([0, 1, 3]),)

What you do wrong is try to accessing the matrix with the bool matrix you get.

```
# This will give you the raws without zeros.
mymatrix[np.all(mymatrix != 0, axis=1)]
```

> array([[1, 1, 1, 1],
>          [2, 2, 2, 2],
>          [3, 3, 3, 3]])

```
# While this will give you the raws with only zeros
mymatrix[~np.all(mymatrix != 0, axis=1)]
```

Given an array like this, `np.where()` is not able to return the indices. It doesn't know what you ask for.